# How to convert annual rate and SD to monthly rate and SD?

Tags: assumptions, descriptive-statistics

If I assume that a survival rate and its SD remain roughly the same for each month, how do I convert an annual rate and SD to a monthly rate and SD? All I know is the annual rate and SD, and the beginning population size.

Comment: Can you provide some context for this? Are you talking about something like the interest rate on a savings account?

Comment: For a prevalence rate, or survival specifically. Let's say the annual survival rate is 0.5 for a bird, and the SD 0.01. If I assume they remain constant for each month, how would I convert the rate and SD into a monthly rate and SD?

Comment: You should probably edit that into the body of your question, rather than leave it in the comments. Also, do you know the size of the population of the birds? Are you assuming the rate is steady, or would it be increasing over the course of the year, eg?

Comment: I'm assuming the rate is constant for each month.

Comment: @WenBaldron This looks very similar to a post you gave earlier today with regard to meta-analysis.  Did you delete that question?

Comment: Please edit the information into the body of your question, rather than leave it in the comments. Do you know the size of the population of the birds?

Comment: Let's just say it's size n (there are a lot of different populations I'm looking at).

Comment: You divide by 12

Comment: My previous suggested answer was 1/sqrt(12) which is the SD for a U[0,1] random variable. gammer is correct if he is referring to the monthly rate and not its standard deviation.

Comment: Well I think you  have $r_1^{12}  = r_{12} $ if by the survival rate you actually mean probability of surviving a given period of time given survived till start of period. So you would take the 12th root of yearly survival probability. And the sd would be more complicated...